# serving static assets from publicdir not working

Tags: vuejs3, vite

Not sure if the problem is related to `vuejs` or the `vite` itself.. I have static images that are never changed. However referencing these resources dynamically from the component - results in file not found error..

`MyComponent.vue`

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { coinName } = defineProps({
  coinName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const iconSrc = '/assets/img/coins/' + coinName + '.svg'
//const iconSrc = new URL('./assets/img/coins/' + coinName + '.svg', import.meta.url).href
//const iconSrc = new URL('../assets/img/coins/' + coinName + '.svg', import.meta.url).href
//const iconSrc = new URL('./../../assets/img/coins/' + coinName + '.svg', import.meta.url).href
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="iconSrc" alt="" />
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

the error I am getting is

> GET http://localhost:5173/assets/img/coins/BNB.svg 404 (Not Found)

no matter which `iconSrc` is used..

as per [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options#publicdir) I have configured the `publicDir` property for `vite`

> Directory to serve as plain static assets. Files in this directory are served at / during dev and copied to the root of outDir during build, and are always served or copied as-is without transform. The value can be either an absolute file system path or a path relative to project root.

`vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
      }
    },
    publicDir: 'public'
  }
})
```

the project structure is pretty much as in default `vuejs3`starter template:

```
/dist
/src
/public
/public/favicon.ico
/public/assets/img/coins/bnb.svg
/public/assets/img/coins/eth.svg
/index.html
/vite.config.ts
```

as you see I have placed the static images into the public folder so I should be able to access them by a path relative to public folder, i.e. `/assets/img/coins/bnb.svg` but it does not seems to be working when serving the content with `npm run dev` command.

The only thing that seems to work is if I run the `npm run build` then in the `dist` folder, the distributed version of the app contains the necessary images in the given location..

Why aren't the files found during the serve?

Comment: It is important to refer to the file name exactly as it was saved. If the file is named `MyExampleFile.svg`, then referencing it as `myexamplefile.svg` will not work. This thought only occurred to me because your error message indicates that it cannot find `BNB.svg`, but in the folder structure, you specified `bnb.svg`.

Comment: In addition, it may be advisable to fix the root path with [`<base href="/">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) if you intend to reference the `/assets` folder across multiple subpages.

Comment: @rozsazoltan you were correct! the naming is case sensitive! I could not find any related information on this limitation in the official documentation. If you could post an answer - I will gladly accept it after a day or so.. I think this solution might be relevant to other people struggling with the same issue

Comment: @rozsazoltan this is a valid comment.. I have had some issues when loading the page. Surprisingly the `css` file was relative to the page where refresh occurred. Not sure how it's related to static images, but the problem started to occur after I have referenced static assets with `URL` syntax as in my examples above. I have then discovered on some other SO page, that the solution that you have mentioned must be used, so this is a totally valid comment from your side. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

Always make sure to specify the file path accurately, referencing the file name exactly! The use of proper case-sensitive naming is mandatory.

It is important to refer to the file name exactly as it was saved. If the file is named `MyExampleFile.svg`, then referencing it as `myexamplefile.svg` will not work.

#### Setting the root path for Vite

In general, it is recommended to set the root path to the root for every web project so that regardless of the subpath, we can always work with the assets folder located in the root.

```html
<base href="/">
```

#### More information

- [An aside on casing and spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files#an_aside_on_casing_and_spacing) - MDN Docs
- [`<base>` head element, for setting the root path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) - MDN Docs